Heteroscedastic residuals of a VECM estimated by MLE
I have estimated an VEC model in Matlab, and it turns out the residuals are heteroscedastic.
Now, does anyone know how to apply HAC errors to a VEC Model in Matlab?
Alternatively, given the model is estimated with MLE in Matlbab, it is required to have homoscedastic residuals?
